# Is there a way to send a variable to a specific task?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I want to be able to send a variable or something to a specific asyncio task (or similar) so it can skip the sleeping part. Here is the structure i'm using:

```py
async def someFunction():
    x = 'something'
    variable_i_need = False
    asyncio.create_task(someLoop(x, variable_i_need))

async def someLoop(x, variable_i_need):
    while True:
        print(x)
        for i in range(60):
            if variable_i_need:
                break
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def someOtherFunction():
    variable_i_need = True
    #Send this to specific task running someLoop()
```

Is there some way I could do this or anything similar where I can update one task using same loop as x amount of other tasks. I can do it with global variable but it would update all tasks, not just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a global dictionary,

say variable_i_need={} with key= task name and value is True or False

Then from someloop i will check against

`if variable_i_need{x}: break`

Then use:

```
async def someOtherFunction(x):
    variable_i_need{x} = True
```

Comment: Yeah this was way simpler than I thought was possible, thanks!